# c# itextsharp absolute text location multiline

Tags: c#, text, location, itext, multiline

I  need to locate a multiline text in a pdf document. I found two possibilitis

```
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(textPhrase), calculatedX,calculatedY, -rotation);
```

But when I locate the text this way, I just can see the first line and all other lines get cutted.

```
TextField tf = new TextField(writer,
                new Rectangle(calculatedX, calculatedY, calculatedX + width, calculatedY + height), "");
tf.Text = text;
tf.FontSize = font.Size;
tf.Font = font.BaseFont;
tf.Options = BaseField.MULTILINE | BaseField.READ_ONLY;
tf.TextColor = font.Color;
writer.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField());
```

This works good and I can see all lines but the problem is that i can not set attributes like Bold underline....

Can you please help me to find a way, that I can see all lines and set attributes like bold, underline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way:

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(text);
            phrase.Font.Size = font.Size;
            phrase.Font = font;

            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(calculatedX, calculatedY, calculatedX + (width), calculatedY + height);
            ct.AddElement(phrase);
            ct.Go();
```